# Make Fireballs Fly Faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I am using Command Blocks to make a working T.A.R.D.I.S. From Dr. Who. I decided to add an item to drop a fireball below the TARDIS. My commands are as follows:

Repeat Command Block:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"'q' to FIREBALL your enemies"}}}}
```

*comparator*

Impulse Command block:

```
execute @a[score_TARDIS_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~-1 ~ {ExplosionPower:3,direction:[0.0,-1.0,0.0]}
```

*repeater*

Repeat Command Block:

```
/kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"'q' to FIREBALL your enemies"}}}}
```

Now, while these all work fine, the fireball (Middle command block) barely goes 20 blocks down. Since the TARDIS can go up 30 with three button presses, that's kinda bad. I would like to know how to make the fireball goes as far as it does when you punch it.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do to make the fireballs faster is multiply the XYZ direction

So if your direction tag was: `direction:[0.0,-1.0,0.0]` and you want to make i tree times faster then you multiply them by 3 so you become `direction:[0.0,-3.0,0.0]}`

If you want it to go up then you make the Y positive: `direction:[0.0,3.0,0.0]}`

***"I would like to know how to make the fireball goes as far as it does when you punch it."***

Fireballs fly forever until they hit something, so I don't understand your issue with that.
If you have other questions ask just ask them :)

Comment: Thanks! It work way better now! and what I meant was that with the old command, the fireballs would go about 20 blocks and then stop. it seems that they only fly forever if you or another entity (snowball/arrow etc.) hits them.

Comment: @4AC11 For that you'll want to use `power`, which is direction without air resistance, while `direction` has air resistance. Just keep in mind that you must define `direction` for a fireball to exist, though IIRC you can set all values to 0 for it (so that the fireball will both exist and so that the velocity obtained from `power` is not modified by `direction`)

Comment: @Skylinerw so, would the tag be {Power:1}? would that make it go faster?

Comment: @4AC11 It'll be just the same as direction, just the name changed: `{direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0],power:[0.0,3.0,0.0]}`. It's not that it goes faster, but rather it doesn't slow down to a stop because `power` does not consider air resistance while `direction` does.

Comment: @4AC11 I don't know if you use PC cause on PC version fireballs normally fly straight and dont slow down like if you summon one like this `/summon fireball ~ ~ ~ {explosionPower:5,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}` and you punch it you'll see that it doesn't slow down.